# Expand certain rows in a table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, rows, expand

I have a table and want to make some of the rows expandable - clicking on a row will expand several other rows under that parent row. Not all the rows should be expandable. jQuery will be fine. Could anybody give me a hint on how this can be achieved or point to a manual?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We had a similar request on a project at my work.  Here is a quick sample I did on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3rdV/1/).

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="main">
            <td >
                <span class="expand">
                    expand</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                Show
            </td>
            <td>
                Show
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hidden">
            <td colspan="3">
                hidden 1
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hidden">
            <td colspan="3">
                hidden 2
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

And now the jQuery

```
$("td span.expand").click(function() {
    $(this).parents("tr.main").nextUntil("tr.main").toggle();
});
```

This example uses [nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) which will continue to select elements until it hits a defined selector, in this case tr.main

Answer (score 0):

here is some easy tutorial http://designgala.com/how-to-expand-collapse-toggle-div-layer-using-jquery/, just convert to handle table rows, however you should consider using divs

Comment: here is one for table http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/20/Expand-table-rows-with-jQuery-jExpand-plugin.aspx